# modeling a nosql database to achieve maximum performance

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have one football league which has many teams and fixtures. The NoSQL database looks like this:

```
collection: teams, documents: team1, team2...            //about 50 per league
collection: fixtures, documents: fixture1, fixture2...   //about 300 per league
```

Soon there will be more leagues and I do not know how to model the database to achieve the maximum performance.

## Option 1: keep the current model

I could keep the current model and just add to each document a field with the league id.

## Option 2: create sub collections for each league

I could create a sub collection for each league. It would look like this:

```
collection: teams, documents: league1, subcollection: teams, documents: team1, team2...
```

Probably those numbers are too small to make a performance optimization. But I also have collections with documents up to 10k per league.

How would you model the NoSQL database?

Answer (score 3):

The size of the collection make no difference in terms of performance. Firestore automatically shards your indexes and documents to distribute the cost of a query among them.  The only thing that matters is the number of documents you actually read.  So, if you request 10 documents from a collection of size 10000, it performs the same as a query for 10 documents from a collection of size 100000.

Since the size of the collection doesn't matter for performance, you should just model your data in whatever way suits your other requirements or personal preferences.

Comment: "The size of the collection make no difference in terms of performance." -> probably want to be explicit that this is about *read* performance only. The number of writes is a major factor in performance, and frequently a primary reason to choose subcollections or not.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Let's say I want to update all document for a specific league. When all documents are in one collection, then I need to select those I want to update. Instead when the documents for that specific league are already in a subcollection I could iterate through and update all them all. Is this what you meant?

Comment: The issue at hand is the write limits for documents in a single collection.  If you're not going to exceed that rate, then there's no problem.  I suggest reading through the documentation to understand the rate limits, then map those to your particular use case. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions